# LWJGL/OpenGL/JAVA How to render Text with FreeType?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

How can I render Text in `LWJGL/OpenGL` with *FreeType* ?
I find only tutorial is C++, but I don't understand C++.
If there is no tutorial for rendering text with *FreeType*.
How I can rewrite the C++ code in Java?

Comment: I am using JOGL and I am also stuck with this problem. I am even considering using Hershey fonts. Anyone who knows a solution similar to this please share even if this is an old post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small FreeType wrapper in libGDX (Java OpenGL related library). The [FreeTypeFontGenerator](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/extensions/gdx-freetype/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/freetype/FreeTypeFontGenerator.java) class will use FreeType to generate bitmap font of given size. Then you may use it to render your text through libGDX facilities or standard OpenGl facilities:

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new   FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/myfont.ttf"));
FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
parameter.size = 12;
BitmapFont font12 = generator.generateFont(parameter); 
generator.dispose(); // don't forget to dispose to avoid memory leaks!
```

Tweak the `FreeTypeFontParameter parameter` fields to get result you want.
See this [short tutorial on libGDX wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype).

Comment: Hey, @plastique. I am trying to use this code, but it doesn't work. It fails on NPE because of `Gdx.files` is `null`. It is because the libGDX application was not set up, I know that, but I am curious whether there is a way how to make this working without setting up the application.